# How do I configure IIS6 server to allow remote IIS administration

Tags: iis-6, remote-access

I'd like to use my win7 desktop to administer a remote IIS6 server.
How do I configure each machine to enable of the IIS Manager on winows 7.

Bonus Question: include instructions for II7+ too.

Answer (score 2):

ok I found where to install the IIS6 management console.

- Control panel
- Turn Windows features on or off
- Internet Information Services
- Web Management Tools
- IIS 6 Management Compatibility
- IIS 6 Management Console

And to launch the console...  look on the start menu sidebar under 'Administrative Tools'

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS 6.0 Manager from your Win7 desktop.  If you install the SMTP Feature, that will install 6.0 Manager.  IIS6 doesn't require anything specific to be configured except the firewall and that you are an administrator on the IIS6 server.

IIS7 has changed quite a bit.  Remote management isn't enabled by default. That's enabled using the "Management Service" at the server level.  One gotcha is that you need to make sure that the service is set to start automatically, otherwise it won't start after your next reboot.  Do that through services.msc.

With Management Service, once you set it up and turn it on, administrators can manage the server.  You can also grant non-admin users access to individual sites or apps.  That's done using IIS Manager Permissions at the site or app level.

Comment: SMTP? Simple Mail Transfer Protocol?

Comment: Yep, that's the one.